# How to store $_FILES superglobal variables in an array and loop through them to find a match in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm running **if statements** to identify each variable independently. My code is a bit messy and long but it works with no problem. I'd like to see if it is possible to **use an array** to store them and **run a loop** to see if there is a **match**, **instead of using if statements**.

**PHP code...**

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Cfile1"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC1)) {
     echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Cfile2"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC2)) {
     echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Cfile3"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC3)) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Cfile4"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC4)) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Mfile1"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslM1)) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Mfile2"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslM2)) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Mfile3"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslM3)) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_deslizador_Mfile4"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslM4)) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
        }                   
else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
```

Comment: moved to chat if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination[$i])){ echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>"} $i++; don't think you need the else at this point
D'Oh missed a semicolon </script>";

Comment: I fixed it by removing the if() and the echoes. But I get a warning message when I run the code **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: foreach($_FILES["index_deslizador_Mfile$i"] might work

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to PHP, so I may get scolded for this suggestion :)
If you could get $index_deslC# variables into an array, you might be able to do something like this:

```
$i = 1
$destination = array($index_deslC...
foreach($_FILES["index_deslizador_Mfile" . $i]["tmp_name"] as $filename) {
    isset(move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination[$i]) ?
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>" : echo '';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Needs `$index_deslC[$i];` and `$i++;` instead of  `$i .= 1;` ,  there is also a deslM variable to take into account - need to know where he is setting `$index_...`

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks @Steve.

Comment: Not sure how to choose if it is a C or an M - I think that would need to be put in your $destination array at the time of creating it. At the same time the corresponding index could be set then it wouldn't matter what was in it, it would roll out by numbers. You could use a 2D array  `$destination[$i]`  for the file and  ` $destination[$i][$i] ` for the corresponding index.

Comment: Hello @SM0827, I get a syntax error on the "isset line", can you please check your code and tell me what to add or change?

Comment: add `if(isset....`  and keep the {} syntax - the other type ` ? : ` sometimes doesn't play nicely with {}

Comment: @Steve, I was just thinking to add it. Thanks.

Comment: if( isset( move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination[$i]) ) {
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
 }
    $i++;   I still get an syntax error.

Comment: Oh, I see. I will change it back.

Comment: Now I am in dangerous territory but I think you could drop the isset and just keep the `if`  `if(move_uploaded...`

Comment: and still getting a syntax error on this line     **if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination[$i])) ?
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>" : echo '';
    $i++;**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95765/discussion-between-steve-and-jqueryster).

Comment: Try ((move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination[$i]) !== NULL) ?
    echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>" : echo '';